# Cross Browser compatibility span elements not displaying correctly

Tags: cross-browser

I have some html code that works fine with google chrome but not with firefox. Somehow the panels do not display the same. Code is as follows:

```html
<div class="container" style="padding-top:15px">
    <div class="sixteen columns">
        <form method="post" action="">
            <span style='display: inline-block'>
                <input type='text;' name="txtSearch;" style="width: 560px;" value="<?php echo $txtSearch; ?>"/>
            </span>
            <span style='display: inline-block'>
                <select id='catergory' name='catergory' style="width: 120px;height:30px">
                    <option> Option 1</option>
                    <option> Option 2</option>
                    <option> Option 3</option>
                </select>
            </span>
            <span style='display: inline-block'><input name="btSearch" type='submit' value='Search' class='button'/></span>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Display]

Comment: That doesn't look like code to me...

Comment: Sorry!! Error during uploading